# where i can get SpringBoardServices source code

Tags: ios, objective-c

Where can I get `SpringBoardServices.h` and `SpringBoardServices.m` files. I want to write a private framework and include it in my project.

What are the steps, i should follow to write a `private framework` in iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a private framework whose sourde code you cannot get. However, its header is available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders/blob/master/SpringBoardServices/SpringBoardServices.h).